# NullPointerException: How to resolve?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

How to resolver NullPointer in getSubstanciasEsquemasAbertos:

```
public Set<SubstanciaEsquemaAbertoSoroterapia> getSubstanciasEsquemasAbertos() {

    Set<SubstanciaEsquemaAbertoSoroterapia> substancias = new LinkedHashSet<SubstanciaEsquemaAbertoSoroterapia>();

    for (EsquemaAbertoSoroterapia esquema : getEsquemasAbertosOrdenados()) {
        substancias.addAll(esquema.getSubstanciasOrdenadas());

    }
    return substancias;
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry.runtime.ComponentEventException [at context:prontuario/prescricao/CriacaoPrescricao.tml, line 936, column 61]
at org.apache.tapestry.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.triggerContextEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1021)
at org.apache.tapestry.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.triggerEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:934)
at org.apache.tapestry.internal.structure.InternalComponentResourcesImpl.triggerEvent(InternalComponentResourcesImpl.java:154)
at org.apache.tapestry.corelib.components.Form.onAction(Form.java:388)
at org.apache.tapestry.corelib.components.Form.dispatchComponentEvent(Form.java)
at org.apache.tapestry.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.dispatchEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:851)
at org.apache.tapestry.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.triggerContextEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1004)
... 79 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.gov.mg.fhemig.sighfase2.entidade.prontuario.prescricao.ItemPrescricaoSoroterapia.getSubstanciasEsquemasAbertos(ItemPrescricaoSoroterapia.java:442)
    at br.gov.mg.fhemig.sighfase2.web.pages.prontuario.prescricao.CriacaoPrescricao.sucesso(CriacaoPrescricao.java:1480)
    at br.gov.mg.fhemig.sighfase2.web.pages.prontuario.prescricao.CriacaoPrescricao.dispatchComponentEvent(CriacaoPrescricao.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.dispatchEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:843)
    at org.apache.tapestry.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.triggerContextEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1004)
    ... 85 more

Comment: Which line throws the NullPointer?

Comment: What line does the nullpointerexception occur on? And what is the result of `getEsquemasAbertosOrdenados()`?

Comment: **Step through your code with a debugger.**

Comment: Look at the exception traceback, figure out where the null is being detected, and see what pointer is involved.

Comment: @MattBall - Stepping through, with a simple NullPointerException, is rarely necessary.  Simply examining the exception traceback will take you right to the problem about 95% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that either `getEsquemasAbertosOrdenados()` or one of the `esquema.getSubstanciasOrdenadas()` is returning `null`. It's hard to tell without looking at the actual stack trace, you should post it as part of the question.

Comment: Shouldn't we really wait until we have more information, before posting an answer?

Comment: If more information becomes available I'll update this answer, until then this is as far as I can go

Comment: NullPointer in getSubstanciasEsquemasAbertos

Comment: @GustavoDuarte In fact, now that you've posted the stack trace, the problem seems to be in the point where `getSubstanciasEsquemasAbertos()` is being called, not in the method itself. Make sure that the object on which `getSubstanciasEsquemasAbertos()` is being called is not null.